# Writing to SQLite DB while transaction in another connection is opened

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox addon which uses SQLite DB to store data (with a help of wrapper around [mozIStorageConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIStorageConnection). Addon has an options window which is used to manipulate with most of the add-on data.

Users asked to add opportunity to cancel changes they make in that window. In order to implement this for data in DB I used "load" event handler for window which looks like the following:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //...
    // conn is mozIStorageConnection instance.
    conn.beginTransaction();
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('dialogaccept', function(){
        conn.commitTransaction();
    }, false);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('dialogcancel', function(){
        conn.rollbackTransaction();
    }, false);
};
```

The goal was to commit changes to DB when window is closed using "OK" button and roll them back when "Cancel" button is used to close the window.

My addon uses single background context for all FF windows using JS code modules. So it's possible to use other FF windows to work with addon and make some changes in its data. There are other UI elements built into FF window with overlay that are used to modify addon data. But when I use commit/rollback scheme in options window it also affects changes made using other elements of add-on UI.

The ideal solution would be to have two separate connections to DB. One of them would be used by modules that are responsible for changes in options window and operations with this connection would be cancellable. The other one would handle modifications made in overlay elements that wouldn't be rolled back. But SQLite doesn't support multiple writers, so this approach wouldn't work.

Is it possible to implement the functionality I'm trying to achieve? I need to be able to use the same DB for all operations but some of them (those happening in options window) should be cancellable.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).